# Ionic 6 capacitor iOS build failed

Tags: capacitor, ionic6

copy/ios/DerivedData/5B2802FE-35AB-453C-8F09-C0CF1179D51A/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CapacitorCordova.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVPlugin+Resources.o /Users/halfmad/Downloads/Ionic\ Projects/tcrptusacom-invoicing\ copy/node_modules/@capacitor/ios/CapacitorCordova/CapacitorCordova/Classes/Public/CDVPlugin+Resources.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'CapacitorCordova' from project 'Pods')

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you should redo the setup procedure

```
ionic cap sync ios
ionic cap update ios
```

then switch to ios folder, reintall pod or update

```
cd ios
pod install
```

also you can check the doc https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting

Comment: for capacitor 3 projects do `cd ios/App/ && pod install`